# Почему получается NaN?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать зависимость ширины svg от ширины родителя

Для этого завел две переменные ...и их использую

В console.log выводится **100px** это верно, так и должно быть но **svg** должно быть **100px * 2** но выходит **NaN** и я так же понимаю что это не ошибка но и не число ..

Как можно исправить ситуацию ?

```js
let item   =  document.querySelector(".item-svg"),
    x            =  10,
    n            =  0,
    c            =  x*2,
    vh           =  x*6,
    start        =  `m ${n} ${n} h${x} v${x}`,
    c1           =  `c ${n} ${x} ${x} ${x} ${x} ${c}`,
    c2           =  `c ${n} ${x} ${-x} ${x} ${-x} ${c}`,
    finish       =  `v ${x} h ${-x}`,
    con          =  `${start} ${c1} ${c2} ${finish}`,
    svg          =   document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "svg"),
    path         =   document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path"),
    color        =   getComputedStyle(item).backgroundColor,
    parentWidth  =   getComputedStyle(item).width;

   console.log(parentWidth);

    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${c} ${vh}`);
    svg.setAttribute("width", parentWidth*2);

    console.log(svg.getAttribute("width"));

    path.setAttribute("d", con);
    path.setAttribute("fill", color);
    svg.append(path);
    item.append(svg);
```

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
}

.item-svg{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

.item-svg svg{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-svg"></div>
```

речь о этой переменной :  `parentWidth  =   getComputedStyle(item).width;`

Comment: Потому, что `clientWidth` нужно запрашивать у рассчитанных стилей. `width` - то `style`. `clientWidth` - это в `getComputedStyle()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'100px' - это строка, а не число, вы не можете её умножить или сложить. Нужно преобразовать её в число для начала, причём `+` тоже не сработает, он умеет работать только с числами, записанными в виде строки ('100'). Используйте `parseInt`, она умеет работать со строками, которые начинаются с числа

```
svg.setAttribute("width", parseInt(parentWidth, 10) * 2 + 'px');
```